# hyperledger fabric migration to a new environment

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Can hyperledger fabric project be migrated to a new deploy environment without data loss? 
For example, from the old deployment in cloud service provider A to the new deployment in cloud service provider B,
assuming the os and other required software is the same in two cloud service providers.
Is there any advise? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: i don't have a complete answer for this, but, the ledger itself is a file. in theory all you'd need to do is copy this file to the new location and start using it straight away. The world db is not a problem as that can be generated from the ledger at any point

Comment: but i think the ledger file will contain the domain/ip information or other certain info not suitable with new environment.

Comment: setting the peer address with domain address than ip address may be helpful to the migration of fabric data to a new environment?

Comment: I don't think any IP/domain name is stored in the ledger/s.

Comment: Any update on this? Did you migrate successfully?